# Long-polling (user notification) with a RESTful architecture

Tags: node.js, rest, long-polling

I'm working on a simple RESTful api (on NodeJs). I understand that being restful implies that horizontal scaling will be much easier. Unfortunately, I need some way for clients to be notified of certain events almost instantly. For this reason, I was thinking of doing long-polling. The question I have is how this work with multiple servers. For instance, here's a simplified used case:

```
Both servers A and B are behind a common load balancer.
User Alice posts a message on Bob's wall (PUT request on server A).
If Bob is online, he should be notified instantly (long-polling on server B).
```

How can server A send a notification to Bob, or server B know that Bob should be notified?

Comment: If both server A and server B are updating the same database, all server B has to do (or whatever server is being long polled, it can be either) is on an interval, check for changes in the database. When one is found, return a response to the client. If you need more real-time than that, you'll want to move to push notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I don't know why you wouldn't just use something like `socket.io` on both client and server to handle your notification channel.  That will use web sockets if available (more efficient than long polling) and then fallback to long polling if no web sockets.

There are a number of ways to handle the issue of notifying a user that may not be connected to the server that originates the notification:

### Connected Database

When a user connects, they are load balanced to a random server, but which server they end up connecting to is stored in a central database (e.g. perhaps a redis store) from which any of your servers can find out which server any user is currently connected to.  This gives you the ability to lookup which server any user is currently connected to.  Each server that handles user connections just adds each user to the database with a reference to their server id when they connect and removes them from the database when the user disconnects.  Note: since this information doesn't need to be stored persistently to disk and the size of the data is small, you can select a database that excels at keeping most or all of the info in memory.

### Hashed Connection

Based on some well-known characteristic of the user such as their userID, a hash value is computed and a repeatable algorithm is created to map hash values across the server pool.  This is a predictable assignment.  Thus, when a server wants to notify Bob, they can call the same function that will figure out which server Bob has connected to.  The hash algorithm can be adaptive such that if today you have three servers, the hashed users are spread evenly among the three servers and if tomorrow you have four servers, then the hashed users are spread evenly among the four servers.

### Multi-Connection

Since low-activity websockets are pretty scalable these days, all users could connect to all servers and thus each server would have a socket connection to the user.  This is simpler infrastructure, but not ultimately as scalable.

Comment: I could have a notification channel using socket.io. I could even have a separate server that only handles notifications. The thing is, everything in my case is stateless, even that notification could be (for instance if a client checked updates on his wall every X seconds instead of receiving a notification). Having a socket connection breaks that statelessness and makes scaling harder.

Comment: @Nepoxx - you're fooling yourself if you think long polling is more stateless than a WebSocket.  It's not.  Both have a connected socket between client and server.  The difference is that websocket is much more efficient than long polling for instantly delivering push message from server to client.  That's why it was invented.  If you want to know which server a given client is connected to without storing additional state, you can use either the Hashed Connection or Multi-Connection algorithm described above (though IMO, neither is as useful as the Connected Database solution).

Comment: @Nepoxx - You said "makes scaling harder".  What makes scaling more work is your desire to deliver real-time push notification message to the client.  websockets were invented because they are MORE efficient than long polling which is what people used before they had websockets.  Both maintain a TCP connection between client and server.  Long polling regular drops and re-establishes that connection (unneccessary overhead when it times out) while a web socket just keeps a single socket open for instant communication.  It appears you are operating under a few false assumptions.

Comment: @Nepoxx - If you want to efficiently deliver real-time messages to the client and you want to have a multi-server farm and you want a client to only connect to one of your servers, then you simply HAVE to invent a means of knowing (server-side) which server the user is connected to.  You can make that be algorithmic (the Hashed Connection option above) or you can make it be stored (the Connected Database option above).  Pick one or invent a slightly different algorithm.  Those are your choices.

Answer (score 0):

Long polling approach puts the burden on client to make periodic requests - hence they are separate requests. 
There is not "notifying the client" with Long polling. The client polls.

You can use distributed cache to store the intermediate state information to which both A and B will have access to. Thus Server A and B can take part in the conversation with the client because it is all kept in that distributed cache.

```
Client Alpha Request 1 -> Node A =) Cache it as k,v (Aplha, State<-has request info)
```

Meanwhile one or more Node A,B,C or D works on it and takes its own time.

```
Client Alpha Request 2 -> Node B =) Retrieve Cache it as k,v (Aplha,State <-not done)
(are we done yet?)
```

Meanwhile one Work its Done. Your Request is fulfilled :) i.e.

Node X =) Update cache (Aplha, State <- results)

```
Client Alpha Request 2 -> Node B =) Retrieve Cache it as k,v (Aplha, State<-results)
    (are we done yet?)                      (here you Sir - your results are now ready)
```

WebSockets: Another options is to go for WebSockets instead of Long Polling

```
    Connection between Client and Node A is persistent with bidirectional communication.
```

Comment: "Long polling approach puts the burden on client to make periodic requests - hence they are separate requests. There is not "notifying the client" with Long polling. The client polls."
Doesn't long-polling achieve push notification from the server? Yes the client polls periodically, but the request is left opened until the server replies, or the request times out. You send a "push" notification by replying to an open request.

Comment: It is never a true push. Those periodic requests are actually for read buffers i.e. polling happens internally as the response is being held from writing. But you wanted server B to respond instead of A ? Hence I am saying let it respond (with "I am not done yet") and have it make another request which lands a free node. Unless you want Node A itself to respond. The burden is browser can't use this HTTP connection for anything else unless you are using SPDY.