# One application on multiple servers

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, websocket, load-balancing

I am developing a web based application that needs to use websockets so the users will be able to see the updates in real time.

However there is something that disturbs me. If there are too many clients simultaniously using the application there needs to be a second server running the same application so some of the users will be redirected to it.

Then how do i make the updates which happen on one of the both servers to be seen on the other one? Do i need to program a tcp connection between both of them and message each other when some update happens???

Answer (score 2):

If your users are connected to both servers (e.g. some users connected to one server and some users connected to another server) and you want to broadcast a message to all connected users from one of the servers, then YES you will need to have the server originating the messasge tell the other server to broadcast a message to all of its connected users.  So, YES, the two servers will have to be connected so they can exchange these update commands.

If you had N servers (perhaps where N was even variable over time), then you would probably designate one master server that kept a connection to all the other servers.  Then, when any notification was going to be sent to all connected users, a server would simply notify the master server who would then notify all the servers who would then broadcast to all their users.  When each server starts up, it just connects to the one master server and that's all it has to now about.

Of course, if you only have two servers, you don't need the master server concept.  Each can just connect to the other.

Comment: What tehnique does Facebook use? As far as i know they have few thousands servers and chatting with somebody is in real time?

Comment: @JoroSeksa - I don't know Facebook's architecture.  They are not usually doing what you asked about which is notifying everyone.  Chat from one user to another or even from one user to a small number of users is a completely different problem.  You can read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430246/long-polling-user-notification-with-a-restful-architecture/26430455#26430455) for ideas on how one server of many sends a message to a particular user that isn't necessarily connected to the server that originates the message.  There are multiple different possible strategies.