# Need help to verify if this socket.io code will work on multiple server instances

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Imagine there is a Node.js chatting app. 
It is going to be hosted on AWS that will scale across multiple instances.
The chat server app has this piece of codes that tracks who is online or offline using a variable called "sockets".
This code works on single instance. But will this code fail when the server is scaled across multiple instances?

```
var sockets = {};

io.configure(function () { 
    ...
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('online', function(data){
        if(data.userId){
            sockets[userId] = socket;
            console.log("user " + userId + " connected.");
        }
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        for(var key in sockets){
            if(sockets[key] == socket)
            {
                delete sockets[key]; 
                console.log("user " + key + " disconnected.");
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});    

// check if a userId is connected
// will this still work when multiple server instances
function isUserIdOnline(userId)
{
    return (sockets[userId] != null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not work with multiple instances. `sockets` represent only the users who connected to this particular server, not all the other servers.

The likely answer to this question involves storing who is connected and which server they are connected to in a central database server so any socket server can find out if someone is connected and which server they are connected to by contacting the central database.  Since the data is temporal, an in-memory database like redis could be used.

A realated discussion of various architectural options for using multiple servers to handle connections while solving the "who is online problem and how do I contact them" is [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26430455/816620).

Comment: Hi jfriend, one more question, what about the "room" concept of socket.io? Is that scalable automatically?

Comment: @mkto - I'm not aware of any feature of socket.io that automatically scales across multiple servers.  Chat rooms would be local to one specific server, but broadcasting to all the users connected to a given chat room on any of your servers would not be particularly hard to implement.  You'd just have to tell each server to send X message to everyone in a particular chat room and each server would then carry that command out on behalf of the users connected to it.  My guess is that this problem has been solved before if you search.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I did some search and it appears that some people are relying on redis pub sub to broadcast messages instead of the broadcast methods in socket.io...